# How to declare the predefined struct CLIENT in <rpc/clnt.h> when using python cffi?

Tags: python, c, python-cffi

Struct CLIENT is defined in rpc/clnt.h, but how can instantiate it when using python cffi?

For example,I have a c header file like this:

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
CLIENT* my_init(char* server_ip);
```

And I have the *.so file for the header file.

Function my_init returns a CLIENT, how can I get its return value in python using cffi?

I tried this, but it came out an error:

```
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()
pmlib = ffi.dlopen("my.so")
ffi.cdef("""
    CLIENT* my_init(char* server_ip);
""")
```

Error:

```
cffi.error.CDefError: cannot parse "CLIENT* my_init(char* server_ip);"
<cdef source string>:2:11: before: *
```